# T4 Code Generation missing in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, t4

So I decided to roll up my sleeves and try out the T4 code generation built into VS2008.

I was going to work off of this article:
http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-creatating-your-first-code-generator/

So, I get to this part:  "Click Project->Add New Item in the main menu and select Code Generation->File template in the dialog."  and discover that the Code Generation category is missing on my machine.  (Tried in both a VB and C# project).

Is there perhaps a seperate download to get T4 on your machine?

### Update #1

So, I downloaded the T4 Toolbox from CodePlex:  http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=27563

And things seem sorted out now.  I was under the impression that the download was required for VS2005 but not for VS2008.  Oh well, looks like its a fresh release anyways so is likely worthwhile to download.

### Update #2

It now seems I don't have all the template types shown in the article.  I only have File, Template, Generator, Unit Test
"Generator" is not listed in the article, and there are 3 in the article that I don't have.  Strange....

Comment: Suggestion: discuss this on the CodePlex site. Mr. Sych does answer T4 questions here, but he, or someone else who has used his toolkit would be the only person who could help you with this. Though, at the rate you're going, you'll have it solved in 1/2 hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you happen to use Visual Basic? T4 Toolbox only provides 4 project item templates for VB - File, Template, Generator and Unit Test. The other templates you may have seen in the tutorial screenshots are implemented in C# and generate C# code. It seemed inappropriate to make them available in Visual Basic projects.

Answer (score 5):

Try just creating a text file and giving it a .tt extension. VS should recognize it right away. You may just be missing the template.